# 'MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ServerVersion'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-3.0

I've applied ASP.NET Core 3.1 in my project and I want to create database by code-first approach and use MySQL.
In startup.cs file I got this error:

> CS1061 'MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
>   for 'ServerVersion' and no accessible extension method 'ServerVersion'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder'

How can I solve it?

**in startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContextPool<Alpha.Web.App.ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"],
            mysqlOptions =>
            {
                mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 20), ServerType.MySql);
            }));
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure what version of Pomelo package you have, but there were certain [breaking changes](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/1233) there (*see also this [issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1240)*), so now you need to initialize it a bit differently.

For example, if you want it to auto-detect the version:

```cs
//_connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(
    options => options.UseMySql(
        _connectionString,
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(_connectionString)
    )
);
```

or if you want to set a specific version:

```cs
//_connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(
    options => options.UseMySql(
        _connectionString,
        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21))
    )
);
```

Comment: I was searching hours to find the correct method for .net core 6. This answer led me to search for `new MySqlServerVersion(new Version`  and I found this link: `https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`